# My laptop has been repaired, but RAM doesn't work anymore

Tags: laptop, boot, memory

My laptop broke 2 weeks ago, when I tried to boot it, it did nothing but flashing some lights, and let the CPU fan spin, screen was pitch-black. Brought it to the seller, who shipped it to repair. Yesterday I got my laptop back.

The laptop had 1x4GB RAM in when I bought it, I upgraded to 2x4GB and everything worked fine until it didn't boot anymore. So I removed the RAM I had put in myself, and brought it back to the seller. But when I got it back, I put my extra RAM back in, and it didn't boot. The same situation as before. I took it out and it worked fine.

On the paper that came with my laptop, they said they replaced the RAM, because of some strange reason. How come my extra RAM doesn't work anymore? They replaced my previous RAM with some crummy Chinese Ram, it works, but I want 8GB RAM again. Is my own RAM probably broken too? The replaced RAM is the same type as my own RAM. DDR3-SODIMM 4GB PC3-10600.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: The existing RAM was probably broken, they replaced it with Nanya RAM... And yes, I installed it the same way as before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likeliest scenario is that at some point your RAM got fried which caused your original problem of not being able to boot. The technicians you sent your PC to saw this and changed the RAM thinking --correctly, since you had removed the second RAM chip-- that everything was all right. Unfortunately, the same thing that broke your original RAM probably also affected your new RAM so when you try to put it back in you get the same symptoms. Does your RAM chip smell burnt? Oddly enough, they often do when borked.

I am afraid you will probably need to buy new RAM. As a last resort, try plugging the RAM into a different computer, if that one doesn't boot either you know your chips are fried.

Comment: This is a totally reasonable assessment.

Comment: I think you are right. From 2 of the 16 chips, the the prints are gone (Brand-logo, numbers ect) plus when you hold them against the light, you can see some dark spots, so they are probably burned, (just as you said) which you do not see on the others. Thanks for your help!